# CPU cores configuration in Spark does not work

Tags: apache-spark

I was trying to set up Spark Standalone Mode following the tutorial at 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html.

The tutorial says that we can pass "-c CORES" to the worker to set the total number of CPU cores allowed. Based on my understanding of the tutorial, I tried to use only 16 cores out of 40 cores of my worker machine by starting the cluster using:

${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-all.sh -c 16

Then I ran a job by using spark-submit and looked at the webUI at master:8080. However, it showed that it was still using all 40 cores instead of 16. I read the start-master.sh and start-slave.sh in ${SPARK_HOME}/sbin and I don't think they are actually parsing the arguments.

So the only way I can limit the number of cores of an application at the moment is set the SPARK_WORKER_CORES in ${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark_env.sh

I am wondering how I could use the -c argument as discussed in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I submitted (issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11841) was answered. -c, -m and -d can be only passed to start-slave.sh. And you can only run those scripts on the machine that you want to be used as worker. 
The usage is:

start-slave.sh <masterURL> [options]

For example, to start a slave with 16 cores, we can use:

start-slave.sh spark://master_ip:7077 -c 16

Answer (score 2):

That argument is - as you have seen in the scripts - not supported AFAIK. The correct approach is to use a combination of the

```
spark-defaults.conf, 
spark-env.sh
command line settings e.g.  --executor_cores
```

to indicate the number of cores to use for a given task.

Comment: I believe it is a bug and have posted a ticket on spark jira site at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11841. Is this the correct site for me to post issues?

Comment: That's the correct place . But i never saw any documenation for -c. Only for --executor_cores

Comment: It is at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html. There is a table above the title "Cluster Launch Scripts". Actually -h, -i, -p, --webui-port and --properties-file are supported, but only by start-master.sh. The rest - -c, -m and -d - are not. And I think spark.executor.cores is to set the number of executors per worker node instead of the number of cores per worker node.

Comment: You are thinking of --num-executors. I have used --executor-cores and it does as specified above.

Comment: It seems "spark.executor.cores" in standalone mode means the number of executors per work machine according to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html, which says "The number of cores to use on each executor. For YARN and standalone mode only. In standalone mode, setting this parameter allows an application to run multiple executors on the same worker, provided that there are enough cores on that worker. Otherwise, only one executor per application will run on each worker."

Comment: Sorry, please forget about my last comment... Yea, executor_cores should be the number of cores each executor uses. If you have 32 cores on the worker machine and set this value to 4, you will have 8 executors running with 4 cores each.

Comment: My ticket got answered and I have posted it as the answer. If you don't mind, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sure. Actually your answer is useful to me as well ;)  I did not ever know about those options - and would have wanted to use them in the past. I am even going to upvote your answer